# Avoiding Duplicate Email Sends with Multiple PM2 Instances in Node.js App (Fork Mode) Using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, pm2

I have encountered an issue with my Node.js app running multiple PM2 instances in fork mode. The application sends emails using Nodemailer, and due to the presence of multiple PM2 instances, the same piece of code is executed, resulting in identical emails being sent to the recipient.

How can I prevent this from happening and ensure that only one instance of the code sends the email to the recipient?

Comment: they need to communicate that to one another, possibly using a shared database. you might as well create an `emails` table with a `date_sent` column